# Roblox Attempt to index nil with 'WaitForChild'

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm making a script that is supposed to find the targeted player, if a value inside the player is true, then `MoveTo()`. It outputs an error that says
`Attempt to index nil with 'WaitForChild'`
This is a server script and the error is at `plr:WaitForChild("Crime",1)`.
Here it is:

```
local crime= false
local plr = nil

function findNearestTorso(pos)
    local list = game.Workspace:children()
    local torso = nil
    local dist = 10000
    local temp = nil
    local human = nil
    local temp2 = nil
    for x = 1, #list do
        temp2 = list[x]
        if (temp2.className == "Model") and (temp2 ~= script.Parent) then
            temp = temp2:findFirstChild("HumanoidRootPart")
            human = temp2:findFirstChild("Humanoid")
            if (temp ~= nil) and (human ~= nil) and (human.Health > 0) then
                if (temp.Position - pos).magnitude < dist then
                    plr = game.Players:WaitForChild(temp2.Name,1)
                    print("plr")
                    torso = temp
                    dist = (temp.Position - pos).magnitude
                end
            end
        end
    end
    return torso
end

while true do
    wait(1)
    local target = findNearestTorso(script.Parent.HumanoidRootPart.Position)
    if target ~= nil and plr:WaitForChild("Crime",1).Value==true then
        script.Parent.Humanoid:MoveTo(target.Position, target)
    end

end
```

Comment: If Nifim answered your question, please mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not guarantee that `plr` is set after `findNearestTorso` runs.

You set `plr` in the body of 3 nested if statements.

```lua
if (temp2.className == "Model") and (temp2 ~= script.Parent) then
    --...
    if (temp ~= nil) and (human ~= nil) and (human.Health > 0) then
        if (temp.Position - pos).magnitude < dist then
            plr = game.Players:WaitForChild(temp2.Name,1)
            --...
```

if any of your if statements are not true `plr` will be `nil`

To handle that we can simply change your condition, where the error happens, to check if `plr` is `nil` before the attempt to call `plr:WaitForChild`

```lua
if target ~= nil and plr ~= nil and plr:WaitForChild("Crime",1).Value==true then
```